# Scala REPL. First it says "illegal start of definition", then "error: not found: type" when I try it a different way

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Sorry guys - I know these questions get asked a lot on the Scala forum, but I've tried following posts on here and I've run into a roadblock either way, so I'd be really grateful for any help from please.

I'm using Scala REPL on my Windows Command Line Terminal. I worked through Jason Swartz's "Learning Scala" and tried out the basic exercises, which worked fine. So I tried the coin flip Scala game listed here on this web blog by the author of "Scala Cookbook" (his final code blocks start at the heading "The Complete Source Code"):
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/functional-game-with-a-little-state/

I copied and pasted both code blocks into Notepad and saved the two files as CoinFlipUtils.scala and coinflip.scala and ran the first using:

`scala CoinFlipUtils.scala`

But I got this error message about packages:

`CoinFlipUtils.scala:1: error: illegal start of definition`

`package com.alvinalexander.coinflip.v1`

So I checked the StackOverflow website, and people said to instead use :paste -raw, and then just paste the full code into paste mode to avoid the packages error message. So I did that using the CoinFlipUtils code, but now I get these error messages instead:

```
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
def printGameState(printableFlipResult: String, gameState: GameState): Unit = {
                                                           ^
```

```
    def printGameState(gameState: GameState): Unit = {
                                  ^
<pastie>:22: error: not found: type GameState
    def getUserInput(): String = readLine.trim.toUpperCase
                                 ^
    <pastie>:10: warning: Auto-application to `()` is deprecated. Supply the empty argument list `()` explicitly to invoke method readLine,
    or remove the empty argument list from its definition (Java-defined methods are exempt).
    In Scala 3, an unapplied method like this will be eta-expanded into a function.
    There were compilation errors!
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here. Is the code on the blog post out of date, or perhaps I've just set up Scala REPL incorrectly? I just don't understand. The examples in the textbook were easier, so now I'm confused trying to get a real program to work. Thank you.

Comment: The REPL doesn't work for programs that require multiple files. I would guess that the tutorial uses **sbt** or **mill** as it's build tool to be able to compile all those files.

Comment: Why are you attempting to paste it into the `repl` in the first place? If it's an example from the book that is small enough, just cram it into a single file, and run it as script (without any packages or anything). Once you're done with the book, move on to something like `sbt`.

Comment: Did you accidentally tag this [tag:apache-spark]? I'm not familiar with Spark, but it doesn't seem to be directly relevant here.

Comment: @user. I'm learning Scala to understand the broader Big Data picture, so Hadoop and Spark are part of it, and it was a recommended tag on my post. But you're right, probably doesn't belong on a Scala post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of tickets or discussions about how it should be easier to enter some arbitrary code in the REPL or a script, and then migrate incrementally to a worksheet or standalone code.

The ticket described here is https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4768, which is quite old.

Probably the REPL is used more for smaller snippets; Ammonite shell is used for more robust scripting.

You can precompile some sources:

```
$ scalac -d ab.jar a.scala b.scala
$ scala -classpath ab.jar c.scala
```

where `a.scala` etc have arbitrary source, and `c.scala` has "top-level scripting" statements.

Alternatively,

```
scala -i a.scala -i b.scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 16.0.1).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> new b.B(new a.A)
val res0: b.B = b.B@2349f14d
```

where the source files have ordinary packages.

Comment: @tom-snytt. Thank you. I get all the same error messages using those commands. I think I'll have to try out IntelliJ or SBT for these larger scripts. Yes, the examples from the textbook are just small snippets that can be typed in, so the book's packages chapter only covers short examples that work fine for me in REPL on Windows. There are some good Scala videos on Youtube by Mark Lewis, but he's using a Linux distro.